# how to dispose cells in UITableView when they are not needed?

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-management

I am creating a very long table with images and some text data. I am using resuable cells.
I am getting high memory allocations as I scroll the table down, may be due to new images loads and add to resuable cells.

I want to know is there a way to dispose the resuable cells when they are not in the view.

Please help!

Comment: Are you autoreleasing the cells? I guess you would be doing that. Post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no way to remove the reusable cells as this task is efficiently managed by the table view itself. According to me, but I need to see some code snippet to confirm, you're not disposing the images properly.

A typical case is when you load images using the `-(UIImage *)imageNamed:` method and in such case all images are stored in a OS managed cache which is not as efficient as manual alloc/release.

Another case is when you create the cell and forget to autorelease it. This means that in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method when you instantiate the new `UITableViewCell` you must autorelease it before leaving the method (it will be retained by `UITableView` internal queue).